# Apache LDAP API to Execute a manage-account commad

Tags: ldap, opendj

I m trying to execute OpenDJ's manage-account command through Apache LDAP API.

Command:
./manage-account clear-authentication-failure-times -h hostip -p port -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w xxxxxx -b uid=testuser1,ou=users,dc=test,dc=xyz,dc=com -X

Does anybody know how to invoke above command through Apache LDAP API?
This command clears user's pwdFailureTime in openDJ.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be done via a 'Password Policy State' extended operation with OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.26027.1.6.1. I am unable to find any further documentation on it, and unless the Apache LDAP API either (i) supports that extended operation or (ii) lets you write your own extended operations, you can't do it with that API.

You can write your own extended operations within JNDI/LDAP, but it's not easy, and the apparent lack of documentation of the ASN.1 format is going to make that impossible.

I can't find it in the OpenDJ client API for Java either.